# Jetty 9 - HttpCompliance.LEGACY

Tags: servlets, jetty, httprequest

On Jetty 9, I am trying to write a Handler to handle HTTP requests. Based on [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html) I need to run the following code:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpCompliance;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
public class OneHandler
{
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
  {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    server.getConnectors()[0].getConnectionFactory(HttpConnectionFactory.class).setHttpCompliance(HttpCompliance.LEGACY);
    server.setHandler(new HelloHandler());

    server.start();
    server.join();
} }
```

However, I don't know where to download:
**org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpCompliance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpCompliance` class first showed up in Jetty 9.3.8.v20160314, as part of the continued cleanup for RFC7230 (the HTTP/1.x update to now obsolete RFC2616) spec, allowing deployments to continue to limp along using the older (looser) RFC2616 spec until such time when they no longer have a choice to use RFC2616 (as the rest of the web, and its interconnected infrastructure has upgraded to RFC7230 as well)

Would encourage you to not specify the `HttpCompliance` at all, or use the `RFC7230` settings to be future proof with Jetty, the HTTP spec, and all of the various intermediaries you will encounter that are also upgrading their spec support levels.

The entire concept of `HttpCompliance` will be removed in a future release of Jetty (the `LEGACY` and `RFC2616` options along with it).

*Meanwhile, I'll edit the documentation to remove that line from the example (it should never have been there in the first place)*

Documentation will update on its own in a day or two.

Change to example at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/19e52ab9c48edfe1590603a95637457afa32cfc6